# Stripe security issue

Tags: javascript, php, security, stripe-payments

I'm currently integrating Stripe into my online store. As you can see by the code below, the payment form is inserted into the HTML with the values for each form field. This means that the user could basically change the price of the field, and do fraud.

Is this secure? If not, how can I add security measures?

Thanks! :)

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="deleted_for_demonstration"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: All important stuff should be handled on the server. User can send whatever he wants, don't worry about this, but you must validate incoming data on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? I've never used this before, and some guidance would be nice because I don't know what to do next

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Stripe.JS in which case you wouldn't be required to use the price in a form.

I would try and change your code to flow something like the below...

For instance...

User selects product id `123` via post request on the product page.
Then you store that they have selected this product in the session.

When they checkout...

Use stripe JS on the card details on the frontend which exchange the form card details for a token.

Post this token to the server.

The webserver then calculates the amount based on the products in the session, uses mysql tables to get the prices for them then submits this to stripe along with the token returned to process the payment.

hope this makes sense...

Comment: What does the form look like for that? I get what you mean, I just have absolutely no idea what the code looks like for that

Comment: Tell me some more about your store? Are you using a solution or building it yourself? Do you have a single product or multiple ones? How do you store cart session data?

Comment: I'm building it myself, there's multiple products. The user can purchase multiple products at a time using the checkout button in their cart. The cart is stored as a session which I can access all the info for the products in the cart etc.

Comment: Sure, so at the point when you take them through that checkout send al products from the session.